# Two intercept coefficients in glmnet output

Tags: r, glmnet, intercept

I am not sure I understand why glmnet returns 2 intercepts in its result.
If model matrix already has intercept column, why do we need another intercept for the model?

```
> mm = model.matrix(...)
> colnames(mm)
 [1] "(Intercept)"  "v1" "v2"....

> model.fit = glmnet(mm, resp, standardize=FALSE, family='binomial', nlambda = 10)
> coef(model.fit, s= 1e-05)
  48 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"                        1
  (Intercept)        5.9487109234
  (Intercept)        .           
  v1        0.2580378293
  v2       -0.4693849121
  .....
```

Comment: You need to remove the intercept when defining mm model.matrix(~**-1**, data = myData). That did it for me. Hope it helps

Answer (score 11):

You need to drop the intercept (the vector of 1's) from the `mm` matrix since the `glmnet` package automatically demeans the data and reports the intercept term by default.

Alternatively, you can use the `intercept` parameter to `glmnet` (`TRUE` by default).